# Receiving signal SIGTRAP after instruction "svc 128" on iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, assembly, arm

Every once in a while, while debugging an application on an iPad (OS 6.1.3, SDK 6.1), the program pauses after receiving a `SIGTRAP` signal. I first noticed this happening inside the `stat` function (from `/usr/include/stat.h`), but it's also happening in a few other places, like `semwait_signal` (from `nanosleep`). The most obvious pattern is that it always happens immediately after running the instruction `svc #128`. In the case of `stat`, it returned `0` and there were no errors, so it doesn't seem to indicate any kind of failure state.

Has anyone else experienced this, or know how to get around it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I didn't discover why exactly the `SIGTRAP` was being raised by these basic functions, but this symptom went away when I fixed a larger problem with my iOS project.

The app target and static library targets I was linking in didn't consistently define the preprocessor macro `_DEBUG`, which generated some weird assembly. They had the same levels of optimization, but apparently including/excluding `_DEBUG` made enough of a difference to cause problems.